# Ajax with JSF -( No RichFaces / No Ajax4Jsf )

Tags: jsf

I am using jsf portlets (JSR 168), and i am implementing ajax with JSF ( i have  a text field and select one menu, on entering a char on the text field, should get the matching strings on the menu, an auto completion functionality). but i am not using any jsf adv specs like richfaces / facelets etc.. our project is using jdk1.4 still.

so i have a h:inputText with onkeyup event which calls javascript method and gets the values into select one menu. this works perfectly alright.

but later i am trying to submit the form with the textfield value and selectonemenu values using h:commandbutton.

there comes the issue, the action menthod in jsf bean is not getting invoked.
but when i tried removing the onkeyup event from the h:inputtext it works perfectly.

please suggest me. whatz goin on here.

Answer (score 0):

got it resolved... there was a problem with my selectonemenu, it was not identifying the item when it is pulling from ajax. so replaced it with html select for now, but i will figureout a way to build the f:selectitem through javascript.